# How to select ID with max skill attribute without group by

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

How can i select id with max skill without grouping by id.

I want to keep the record with max(skill) in

```
select ID, max(skill) from skill_table group by ID, skill
```

but when I group by id I will get all the records because its unique key

| ID | Skill |
| --- | --- |
| 89fddc8855819055015581a48fdf000c | 2 |
| 8a12d16c7539f28a01754a884e2801c0 | 1 |

I need to keep ID of skill 2 with something like this

```
CASE WHEN max(SKILL)THEN ID END
```

any suggestions ?

Comment: SELECT ID FROM   skill_table WHERE rownum < = 1 ORDER BY skill DESC;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order by `Skill` in descending order and then get the first row (with ties if there may be many maximum rows):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   skill_table
ORDER BY skill DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES;
```

Use `FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY` if you want only a single row.

If you are not using Oracle 12c or later then use the `RANK` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT s.*,
         RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY skill DESC ) rnk
  FROM   skill_table s
)
WHERE  rnk = 1;
```

Or, if you only want a single row (rather than all maximum values) then, use `ROW_NUMBER` instead of `RANK`.

If you really want to use aggregation then use `KEEP`:

```sql
SELECT MAX(Skill) AS skill,
       MAX(id) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY Skill ) AS id
FROM   Skill_table
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3adc1f7f6364f7abf492fb560fefc57e)*

Comment: Rank function was exactly what i was looking for. Thank you very much